# Laravel 5 single route multiple controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route with parameter

```
Route::get('forum/{ques}', "ForumQuestionsController@show");
```

Now I want a route something like

```
Route::get('forum/add', ['middleware' => 'auth:student', 'uses' => "ForumQuestionsController@add"]);
```

well when I hit `localhost:800/forum/add` I get routed to `ForumQuestionsController@show` instead of `ForumQuestionsController@add`

Well I know I can handle this in show method of `ForumQuestionsController` and return a different view based on the paramter. But I want it in this way.

Comment: nice question..... like it!!

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203020/laravel-single-route-point-to-different-controller-depending-on-slugs?noredirect=1#comment60056797_36203020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give this one

```
Route::get('forum/add', ['middleware' => 'auth:student', 'uses' => "ForumQuestionsController@add"]);
```

Then the following

```
Route::get('forum/{ques}', "ForumQuestionsController@show");
```

Another Method (using Regular Expression Constraints)

```
Route::pattern('ques', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('forum/{ques}', "ForumQuestionsController@show");
```

If ques is a number it will automatically go to the show method, otherwise add method

Comment: Only first is useful as the {ques} parameter is also a string where closure will not work. But also in first what if I had these two routes in different `Route::group()`

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the order of routes to solve the problem.

Place `add` before `show` , and then laravel will use the first match as route .

```
Route::get('forum/add', ['middleware' => 'auth:student', 'uses' => "ForumQuestionsController@add"]);
Route::get('forum/{ques}', "ForumQuestionsController@show");
```

Comment: what if i had these two routes in different `Route::group()`

Comment: @jovanpreet if the ```{ques}``` is number only , you could use ```Route::pattern('ques', '[0-9]+');``` to limit the type of ```{ques}``` .

Comment: Well then maybe you should change the order of group , or rename the route.

Answer (score 0):

I think your {ques} parameter do not get properly. You can try this:

```
Route::get('forum/show/{ques}', "ForumQuestionsController@show");
Route::get('forum/add', ['middleware' => 'auth:student', 'uses' => "ForumQuestionsController@add"]);
```

If you use any parameters in show method add parameters:

```
public function show($ques){
}
```