# Laravel 5.8 single routing but multiple controllers

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-middleware

I'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259618/laravel-5-single-route-multiple-controller-method) for using different controller for my route but didn't work

here is my route code

```
Route::get('{slug}', ['middleware'=>'isPage', 'uses'=>'PageController@view'])->name('viewPage');


Route::get('{modelName}', ['middleware'=>'isUser', 'uses'=>'ModelController@view'])->name('viewModel');
```

and here is middleware code for isUser

```
use Closure;

use App\ModelProfile;
class isUser{
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    $slug = $request->route()->parameter('slug');
    $model = ModelProfile::where([
        ['slug', $slug],
        ['is_status', 'ACTIVE'],
        ['is_deleted', 'NO']
    ])->count();

    if($model > 0){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

and here is my middleware code for isPage

```
use Closure;

use App\Page;
class isPage{
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    $slug = $request->route()->parameter('slug');
    $model = Page::where([
        ['slug', $slug],
        ['is_status', 'ACTIVE'],
        ['is_deleted', 'NO']
    ])->count();

    if($model > 0){
        return $next($request);
    }
 }
}
```

In kernel.php

```
'isPage' => \App\Http\Middleware\isPage::class,
'isUser' => \App\Http\Middleware\isUser::class,
```

Comment: Please read this if you find the solution - `https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27179`

Comment: what happens if a page slug is exactly the same as a user slug ? What you're trying to do doesn't have a good solution.

Comment: @SunnyNegi, are these middlewares registered in `Kernel.php` with aliases? Also, you start your middleware class name with small letters. Is that the same with the class file name?

Comment: @UdoE yes these middlewares are registered in Kernel.php with same as class name / filename

Comment: @N69S no their is no possability coz when we generate slug, we put an unique check in database

Comment: `didn't work` - what does that mean?  What did you try, exactly, and what happened?  If you visit some URL like `/foo`, and that is not a slug, you will get a 404, right?  You cannot have 2 wildcard routes, as the first one will always match everything.  You need instead routes like `/pages/{slug}` and `/users/{modelName}`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic , so how facebook will manage the url can you explain for profile and pages

Comment: Erm, because they have a completely different architecture? :-)

Comment: Once a route matches, that is the route used. `next()` in a middleware passes the request to the next middleware, or to the next level of the application (eg a controller, or validation, etc), not to the next route.