# Laravel same route different controllers for auth and guest users

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-7

I am trying to have the same route homepage `/` but different controllers for auth and guest users but i am unable to do this. I have searched and tried all the results on google, stackoverflow etc, none have worked. I am guessing it is because of the version i am using **Laravel Framework 7.15**

```
 $uses = 'BlogController@index';
 if (!is_null(auth()->user())) {
     $uses = 'HomeController@index';

 }
 Route::get('/', $uses);
```

BlogController is for guest and HomeController is for authenticated users. So when i run the code for authenticated users it shows only shows the Blog(guest) homepage and not users HomeController page.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```php
Route::get('/', (function() {
    return auth()->user()
        ? app()->make(\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class)->index()
        : app()->make(\App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::class)->index();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Error message is = `Action App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index not defined.`

Comment: do you have index method in HomeController ?

Comment: Yes I do. It works with a straight up `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: sr, just updated my answer. redirect route action only works when you already have that action. So now we should make controller class and call the index function, but i think there will be another fluent way to do that. Will update the better answer when i found it

Comment: but i suggest you should try this solution, handle view in the controller is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618735/laravel-routes-same-route-different-controllers

Comment: Thanks the updated answer works perfectly now. I tried the answers to the recommended question before posting mine on here, and it didn't work. But yours worked!

Comment: @bangnokia Hey I am trying to add middleware `verified` to the route but I don't know where to add it. Can you help me on this one?

Comment: Apparently the route is bypassing my `$this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']` instance in my construct function in the `HomeController`

Comment: @bangnokia So I figured I have to add it to the route,

Comment: @ObinnaIloeje append your middleware to the end like this `Route::get('/',...)->middleware('auth', 'verify');`

Comment: @bangnokia You don't understand, I am asking how to append `middleware` to the route you gave me. If I append it the regular way as you stated, it will not show the `guest` index page...